# SVG not filling whole Viewport on mobile view

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox, wave

I have a problem with all wave SVG’s across my website. Does anyone know how to make an SVG fill the whole viewport/width of the screen?

I used [Wave SVG generator I used](https://getwaves.io) to make the waves, and uses a div.

```
<nav>
<div> //align-content: space-between
   <svg>

   <main></main>

   <svg>
</div>
<footer>
```

The space between is to push the svg’s to the top and to the bottom and get the text-content in the center.

[image: The Problem visualized with red arrows]

Comment: Do you use a `main` element inside the svg element? Also: do you have an svg element without a `viewBox` attribute?

Comment: No the code I posted was just to visualize, I wrote this on my phone. The main element is outside the svg element. The svg has a viewBox attribute.

Comment: Please edit the question so it has a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

It could be a generated SVG file issue. You can manage it with simple CSS trick.

```
.svg-parent-div {
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
}

svg {
width: calc(100% + 2px);
margin-left: -1px;
}
```

**UPDATED**

An accurate code for your case

```
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}

svg {
width: calc(100% + 2px);
max-width: calc(100% + 2px); /*important in your case*/
margin-left: -1px;
}
```

Comment: There is now no gap on the left side, but a gap on the right side.

Comment: is there a working online example? I'd like to see a link to find you best working solution.

Comment: Maybe try `width: calc(100% + 4px); `

Comment: Live example here: https://freibj.github.io/geneever/partners.html

Comment: Updated an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by a slight difference between the SVG `viewBox` aspect ratio, and the aspect ratio of the specified (or calculated by the browser) SVG `width` and `height`.

Try adding `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to the `<svg>` element of that SVG.

```
<svg ...  viewBox="..." preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

or possibly:

```
<svg ...  viewBox="..." preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice">
```

Comment: A little late, but this one worked for me (using .net MAUI Blazor Hybrid with HTML + CSS)